# Pass the column names from a list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list of column names which varies every time. The column names are stored in a list. So, I need to pass the column names from the list (in the below example its id and programid) to the when clause and check if both the columns are holding null values. Please help me with the solution.

Pyspark Code:

```python
ColumnList = ['id','programid']

joinSrcTgt.withColumn(
    'action', 
    when(joinSrcTgt.id.isNull() & joinSrcTgt.prgmid.isNull(),'insert')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to check if each column is null:

```python
[col(c).isNull() for c in ColumnList]
```

Then you can use `functools.reduce` to bitwise-and (`&`) these together:

```python
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

ColumnList = ['id','programid']

joinSrcTgt.withColumn(
    'action', 
    when(
        reduce(lambda a, b: a&b, [col(c).isNull() for c in ColumnList]),
        'insert'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Pault. It worked. Can you also tell me how to include the below condition in when clause. I want to compare the columns present in 2 lists.  column1 = ['id', 'programid'] column2 = ['src_id', src_programid'] joinSrcTgt.withColumn(
    'action', when((joinSrcTgt.src_id == joinSrcTgt.id) & (joinSrcTgt.src_programid == joinSrcTgt.programid) & (joinSrcTgt.src_checksum != joinSrcTgt.checksum),'upsert')

Comment: @Shivhar if you have a different requirement, either edit it into your question or post  a new question if the new requirements are sufficiently different than the original question. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once and don't post code in the comments.